# iOS remote notifications do not trigger when in background mode

Tags: ios, iphone, azure, xamarin, push-notification

I do not usually post here, but this time I am stuck. I searched already on this forum, on stackoverflow and on google in general but I cannot understand what I am doing wrong.

I am developing a Xamarin.Forms app and I am having trouble to fire the methods when a remote notification is received.
Here is my code:

Just after login I execute this method to register to apple notification center:

```
public void RegisterForNotifications ()
{
        var settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(
            UIUserNotificationType.Alert
            | UIUserNotificationType.Badge
            | UIUserNotificationType.Sound,
            new NSSet());
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(settings);
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();
}
```

this call successfully trigger this method on AppDelegate

```
public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications (UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
{
    var azureService = App.GetBackEndService ();
    azureService.RegisterForNotifications (deviceToken);
}
```

RegisterForNotifications registers with azure notification hub:

```
public static async void RegisterForNotifications(this BackEndService service, NSData deviceId)
{
            Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceClient client = new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceClient (service.Client.ApplicationUri);
            client.CurrentUser = service.Client.CurrentUser;
            var push = client.GetPush ();
            var tags = new List<string>() { App.GetBackEndService().Client.CurrentUser.UserId };
            try{
                await push.UnregisterAllAsync(deviceId);
            }catch(Exception e){
                var exp = e.Message;
            }
            await push.RegisterTemplateAsync(deviceId, NOTIFICATION_TEMPLATE, "", "NotificationTemplate", tags);
}
```

Now, when I send a notification and the app is on foreground the method triggered is this one (In AppDelegate):

```
public override void ReceivedRemoteNotification (UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo)
{
    ShowAlerts (userInfo);
}
```

But when in background mode (for example when I press the Home button on the Iphone) nothing gets triggered
And nothing shows on the upper bar where the iOS notifications are usually shown.
I placed a breakpoint in ReceivedRemoteNotification, DidReceiveRemoteNotification and also on FinishedLaunching.

I properly set Remote notifications  in Info.plist under Enable Background Modes

Can someone understand what I am missing?

Comment: Assuming you have implemented "UIKit.UIApplicationDelegate.DidReceiveRemoteNotification" (with the `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` selector, does your notification carry a payload (even pseudo), i.e. `content-available = 1`

Comment: Yes I do implement "DidReceiveRemoteNotification" but it never gets fired (both foreground and background). My notification carries  a payload indeed which I can retrieve from "ReceivedRemoteNotification" => NSDictionary userInfo

Comment: I am going to update this.
I managed to hit "ReceivedRemoteNotification" (in background mode) only from 
azure mobile services > notification hub > debug

and sending this paylod :

{"aps" : {"content-available" : 1, "sound": ""}}

Now my question is, is it possible to achive this from a .NET backend using the templates?
Looks like I am doing something wrong